# Angular 5 form custom validation is not working properly

Tags: regex, typescript, angular5

I am working on Angular 5 and I have a form with a field username. I want to integrate a custom validation for minimum character length and avoid blank space.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control " id="account-details-username" placeholder="" formControlName="username" >
        <div *ngIf="form.get('accountDetails.username').touched && form.get('accountDetails.username').invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="form.get('accountDetails.username').errors.required">Username is required.</div>
          <div *ngIf="form.get('accountDetails.username').errors.minimumSix">Username must contain at least 6 characters</div>
          <div *ngIf="form.get('accountDetails.username').errors.blankSpace">Username does not contain blank space.</div>
        </div>
```

I tried to create a custom method for that. But invoking the first condition only.

```
test(control: any) {
console.log(control.value);
let minimumSix = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,}");

if (!minimumSix.test(control.value)) {
  return { 'minimumSix': true };
}

if(control.value.match("^\\s+$")) {
  console.log("blank");
  return { 'blankSpace': true };
}

return null;
}
```

Not checking the blank space validation.

Comment: Maybe it can be solved by adding `ng-trim="false"` to `input`?

Comment: Do I get you right? Your problem is, that the "blank-validation" isn't working at all?

Comment: Yes @DiabolicWords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following solution, when it comes to blanks.

```
const blankSpace = /^\S*$/;

if (!blankSpace.test(control.value)) {
    console.log("blank");
    return { 'blankSpace': true };    
}
```

So your full method should look like this:

```
test(control: any) {
    const minimumSix = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,}");
    const blankSpace = /^\S*$/;

    if (!minimumSix.test(control.value)) {
      return { 'minimumSix': true };
    }

    if (!blankSpace.test(control.value)) {
        console.log("blank");
        return { 'blankSpace': true };    
    }

    return null;
}
```